# the difference when using the initialization function in php

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection

I'm not understanding how to use the initialization function in the code below. Can you explain it to me?

```
   Class A
   {
       protected $classB;
       public function __construct()
       {
           $this->classB = new ClassB();
       }
   }

   Class A
   {
       protected $classB;
       public function __construct(ClassB $classB)
       {
            $this->classB = $classB;
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the second way you always have to make your object like this. 
$clasa = new ClassA($classb);
in  the first way you are creating the object inside of the constructor.
the second way is an injection. and could be usefull when for example you need some attributes already seted in the object.